# How to set TextView after other element

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I have a xml file with the design of my app. In this one, I want to set a TextView after a LinearLayout. But how can I do this? It displays it always in my other elements. Is there something like a "margin_top_elemnt_by_id"? I hope you know what I mean.

I talk about post_view_maintext

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="1440px"
    android:layout_height="1000px"
    android:id="@+id/post_view_photo"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_image"/>



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/post_view_photo"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/post_view_photo"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/post_view_photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_username"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#414141"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/post_view_maintext"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your layout xml file here?

Comment: please provide your xml code

Comment: yes, I posted it @Wilik

Comment: yes, I posted it @inkedTechie

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_below`.

```
   <LinearLayout
...>
    <ImageView
         .../>
    <TextView
        ...
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagevViewID"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    .../>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/textviewID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewID"
    .../>
</LinearLayout>
```